# Database app approach

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data, wrapper

I am digging in this forum but could not realize which way to start. 
I need to build an app in Swift that searches in its internal database for a ZIP CODE and retrieves the street name, just two columns ZIP and Street but it is a list of more than 20K ZIP codes lines.
The user will be able only to search not edit, add nor delete.
 I learned and please correct me if I am wrong: 
CoreData is good for small databases, and can not import from a list of ZIP codes I already have, neither allows to open the coredata database to edit/copy or add outside of the app, so How Apple wants us to use CoreData if the users must populate the database in the iphone.
SQLite in Swift is fast but there is not many good tutorials in the internet, most of them show only how to work with CoreData.
 I just found one or two tutorial in Swift SQLite. No one shows how to import data from other database, To work with SQLite in Swift I will need a wraper like FMDB or SwiftData, the documentation is too technical for my knowledge so I have no idea which one should I go.
Hope somebody can help me and show me the direction and maybe some help in this journey as well.

Jade.

Comment: The intent of CoreData is to make objects persistent.  The fact that it often uses a database to do so isn't the main point.  Since that's not really your goal, it's probably not the right tool.  You probably want to create and populate a SQLite database as a side-project outside your app and package the result when the app is built.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is a Framework that will help you build the Model (in a Model/View/Controller app) of your App. Core Data is not database technology.

It helps you persisting your data. For that, you can save data in memory (fast & good for testing), in binary, XML form (not in iOS, yes in Mac) or using a SQLite DB as storage.

The normal use scenario is to store Core Data's objects inside a SQLite database. So it's not a "should I select between SQLite / Core Data". It's more a "I'll learn Core Data and it will use SQLite under the hood"

Using Core Data you can do full CRUD in memory (inside a CD Context) that gets saved in DB. So you can import your ZIP codes inside a DB and then access them just in read only mode (just querying Core Data). Querying in Core Data == fetching

You can then bundle that Pre-populated DB with your app and use it. Why? Because Core Data plays nicely with UIKit, so UITableViewController, for example, fits perfectly with NSFetchResultsController

It's a steep learning curve, but it'll pay off if you keep using data you want to persist in your apps.

Comment: Thank you Diego.... I am wondering if you know any link or tutorial which show how to bundle my DB, I tried but it seems not working in the iphone/ipad test, only in the simulator seems to work and after I exit Xcode the data is lost :(

Comment: I agree with Diego entirely. It is a steep learning curve but it will pay off in mountains of programming happiness when you learn to use it well. There are a number of ways to do the things you ask. My suggestion is that you learn to do each step, search for help on SO and ask specific questions when necessary. You should really ask a separate question for each task you are attempting to achieve. Hope that helps :)